# Why don't we use numpy structured arrays to do data analysis ? I

Tags: pandas, numpy

Why is it so that we use pandas for data cleaning and analysis ? I understand that it has the import csv functions and other convenience methods, but could we do most or all of the work only using numpy ?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned it's just that. Most of the things I use pandas for I know how to do in numpy but it's more verbose.

Comment: Why questions like this aren't very well suited to SO.  Too much room for vague opinions, and too dependent on experiences, or lack there off.  We see structured arrays most often a csv is loaded with `genfromtxt` and `dtype=None`.  `pandas` csvreader generally does as well if not better.  pandas has more tools to do Series specific tasks.  But it's not an either/or issue.  Just look at the questions with both tags, or ones trying to speed up pandas code ("removing loops").

Comment: pandas was built over numpy to offer better interface. But you can use numpy (I do sometime, just a dictionary with numpy instead of pandas), or xarrays (you can see something in between of the two), etc. Remember: **my use case is not your use case**, so we cannot answer for you, but I know pandas is useful on many case (and numpy on other cases).

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I have my answer. @hpaulj I will keep this in mind.